# How to load a flat file from a URL to SQL Table

Tags: sql

I need to download a CSV file from a URL to a SQL Table. In this case, the url looks like the following: http://mysource.com/mypage.aspx?text=All. This points to a Excel CSV file. I need to load the data from this file to a SQL Table periodically, like every 5 minutes, for example.

I'm attempting this from within the SSIS environment to create a package, but it appears that perhaps the file should be downloaded using a script first? Or can this be done within SSIS. The File System Task or Flat File Source doesn't like the url input string, nor does FTP.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see this? http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx or http://ssisdownloadfiletask.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple samples that do what you want:

http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/download-source-file-from-website-with.html

-t.

Comment: Straight forward solutions as referenced above. I created the script per the 2nd link with my parameters. I added the dtsx file to SQL Agent and everything worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best possible way is to create a script task and write some c# to do it. As far as I know you can only FTP via SSIS.

Pre-requisite you need to know c#

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One of my goals is to use the tools available and reduce maintenance, i.e. I'd rather maintain a dtsx package than a dtsx package and script/dll/wcf, etc. It seems that this basic task should be able to be accomplished with SSIS and Sql Agent. SSIS is preferred as I need to map the flat file to the SQL table.